# Using AWS Javascript SDK with NativeScript

Tags: aws-sdk, nativescript

I'm planning to build an app using Nativescript. However, I want to integrate AWS services in the app architecture.

Please, can someone tell me whether I can use AWS JS SDk with nativescript or not.
If yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about AWS but you may use any JavaScript library / module in NativeScript environment as long it doesn't depend on any browser / node specific features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use AWS SDK with NativeScript. I am using it to upload files to S3. You need to install it using

```
npm i aws-sdk
```

File upload to AWS S2 example
In your component file, import it

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const AWSService = AWS;
    const region = 'Your_Region_name';
    this.bucketName = 'bucketName ';
    const IdentityPoolId = 'IdentityPoolId';

    // Configures the AWS service and initial authorization
    AWSService.config.update({
      region: region,
      credentials: new AWSService.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId
      })
    });

    // adds the S3 service, make sure the api version and bucket are correct
    this.s3 = new AWSService.S3({
      apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
      params: { Bucket: this.bucketName }
    });
this.s3.upload({ Key: 'test/' + file.name, Bucket: this.bucketName, Body: file, ACL: 'public-read' }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, 'there was an error uploading your file');
      }
      console.log('upload done');
    });
```

P.S. You need to create a Idendity pool in cognito if you don't have one.

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'timers'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'