# AWS S3 upload fails on nativescript

Tags: amazon-s3, nativescript

I'm trying to connect my Nativescript app with an Amazon S3 account in order to be able to upload profile pictures of my users. I'm using the Nativescript-aws-sdk plugin for this. The error message that I'm receiving is the following: "`The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 2.)`"

I've tried the plugin with my key and secret key but that resulted in the same error. I've given my S3 account an policy and added CORS settings. What am I doing wrong?

```
S3.init({ endPoint: '', accessKey: '', secretKey: '', type: 'static' }); // <= Try calling this before the app starts
```

```
const s = new S3();
const uploadingFileID = s.createUpload({
  file: filePath,
  bucketName: 'bucket',
  key: `1`,
  acl: 'public-read',
  completed: (error, success) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`Upload Failed :-> ${error.message}`);
    }
    if (success) {
      console.log(`Upload Complete :-> ${success.path}`);
    }
  },
  progress: progress => {
    console.log(`Upload Progress: ` + progress.value);
  }
});
```

Comment: Checkout the related [issue here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/420), it seems to be the policy issue with your bucket.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697732/3840213

Comment: Thanks for you replies. Unfortunately I still haven't been able to get it to work. I've tried a lot of different policies, but no luck so far. However, using the same policies and credentials I am perfectly able to access s3 through the cli. As for narendra's suggestion, that plugin requires nativescript-nodeify, which doesn't work with webpack. Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance!